# Clone TFS-GIT repository to GIT repository (Linux) by using GIT commands

Tags: linux, git, tfs, version-control

1. We have Redhat Linux server, GIT was already installed on this server and we need to create a local repository.
2. We have TFS-GIT project in TFS 2015, we need to clone the TFS-GIT repository to the GIT repository on Linux by using GIT commands.

For this task, we created a empty local repository on Linux, and getting 
**"Fatal: authentication error to connecting TFS-GIT repository on windows server 2012** . We tried in different ways but still we are getting same error.

can any one please advise on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As present time, you need to configure Basic Authentication on your TFS Application Tier server in order to authenticate from Linux (or OSX).

Note that if you do this, you should also enable SSL so you can use HTTPS, because **Basic Authentication sends credentials in cleartext, including passwords**. Using HTTPS will ensure that the credentials are encrypted.

Comment: I added basic ahuthentication  method by using server manager and also specified the name@domain in that. then I installed the centralized SSL certificate support on the same server. Still am getting same error. Please advise me on this

Comment: Did you enable Basic Authentication on the `/tfs/` virtual directory, or the root website?