# Clone TFS-GIT repository to GIT repository (Linux) by using GIT

Tags: linux, git, github, tfs

1. We have Redhat Linux server, GIT was already installed on this server and we need to create a local repository.
2. We have TFS-GIT project in TFS 2015, we need to clone the TFS-GIT repository to the GIT repository on Linux by using GIT commands.

For this task, we created a empty local repository on Linux, and configured the basic authentication and configured the SSL certification by using server manager.

Still getting **"Fatal: authentication error"** to connecting TFS-GIT repository on windows server 2012 . We tried in different ways but still we are getting same error.

Am using my basic credentials like which I used for server logins and I have only id and password for everything.

Is there any specific kind of passsord I need to use for this?
Please advise me on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone TFS-GIT repository to GIT repository (Linux) by using GIT commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770709/clone-tfs-git-repository-to-git-repository-linux-by-using-git-commands)

Comment: Don't repost a question. If you want to get more attention on your existing question, edit it to include additional details.

Answer (score -1):

You have done all as it should be.
You need to copy your public key of the desired user to the Unix server as well so it will work.

### ***`How to setup ssh-key?`***

```
# generate the key (local machine)
ssh-keygen -t rsa

# copy the generated key to your unix machine (server)
# the key is in : %HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
# In widows its under your user account: Users/<user_name>
```

---

### ***`Other ways`***

If you have only username and password you might need to use http/https.
[Read here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.html) how to set it up/

Comment: TFS doesn't support SSH keys for authentication yet. It's coming.